# Pass a variable in a shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I'm new to Unix...I have a shell script that calls sqlplus. I have some variables that are defined within the code. However, I do not feel comfortable having the password displayed within the script. I would appreciate if someone could show me ways on how to hide my password.

1. One approach I know of is to omit the password and sqlplus will
   prompt you for the password.
2. An approach that I will very much be interested in is a linux
   command whose output can be passed into the password variable. That
   way, I can replace easily replace "test" with some parameter.
3. Any other approach.

Thanks

```
#This is test.sh It executes sqlplus
#!/bin/sh
export user=TestUser
export password=test
# Other variables have been ommited
echo ----------------------------------------
echo Starting ... 
echo ----------------------------------------
echo
sqlplus $user/$password
echo
echo ----------------------------------------
echo finish ... 
echo ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Don't use `export` unless you know that you have a compelling reason to do so -- it exposes the password to any process which can run `ps -E` as the same account (at best), or potentially every user on the same machine (at worst). `user=TestUser`, with no `export`, will set a variable local to the shell, which is generally good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the password to the sqlplus command:

```
echo ${password} | sqlplus ${user}
```

Comment: Quotes. `echo $password` will change a password, of, say, `abc * def` to `abc`, followed by a list of names in the current directory, and only then `def`. You need this to be `echo "$password"` (or `echo "${password}"`, if you really insist on extra verbosity that adds no value in this case) to be safe.

Comment: not necessarily. :) i assumed the poster used bash, but the question is tagged simply [unix] and [shell].  zsh does not do wordsplitting of parameter values by default.

Comment: @justsomebody POSIX sh requires wordsplitting, making that behavior the safe assumption, and zsh nonconformant in that respect. POSIX sh is, after all, the **standard** (in the formal, standards-body-approved sense) UNIX shell syntax; ash is (fairly) closely conforming, bash is a large superset, and zsh simply noncompliant. (Yes, it's noncompliant in places where the standard is bloody stupid, but, well, it's a standard, and is what it is).

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: passwords on the command line are prone to exposure to hostile code and users.  don't do it.  you have better options.

the command line is accessible using `$0` (the command itself) through `${!#}` (`$#` is the number of arguments and `${!name}` dereferences the value of `$name`, in this case `$#`).

you may simply provide the password as a positional argument (say, first, or `$1`), or use [*getopts(1)*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html), but the thing is passwords in the arguments array is a bad idea.  Consider the case of `ps auxww` (displays full command lines of all processes, including those of other users).

prefer getting the password interactively (stdin) or from a configuration file.  these solutions have different strengths and weaknesses, so choose according to the constraints of your situation.  make sure the config file is not readable by unauthorized users if you go that way.  it's not enough to make the file hard to find btw.

the interactive thing can be done with the shell builtin command `read`.

its description in the *Shell Builtin Commands* section in *bash(1)* includes

> `-s`  Silent mode.  If input is coming from a terminal, characters are not echoed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

INTERACTIVE=$([[ -t 0 ]] && echo yes)

if ! IFS= read -rs ${INTERACTIVE+-p 'Enter password: '} password; then
  echo 'received ^D, quitting.'
  exit 1
fi

echo password="'$password'"
```

read the bash manual for explanations of other constructs used in the snippet.

configuration files for shell scripts are extremely easy, just `source ~/.mystuffrc` in your script.  the configuration file is a normal shell script, and if you limit yourself to setting variables there, it will be very simple.

for the description of `source`, again see *Shell Builtin Commands*.

Comment: It's worth noting that passing a password on a command line is an exceptionally bad thing to do from a security perspective -- any other process on the system, including sandboxed/untrusted programs running as `nobody`, can read it off the command line.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you seem to have missed "passwords in the arguments array is a bad idea" in the answer.

Comment: Yes, I did -- and I missed it on rereading again, too. That's a hint that it maybe needs to be louder. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: is it loud enough now? ;)